# Prove $\sup (A \cap (-\infty, x]) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} $ if and only if $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. Prove $\sup (A \cap (-\infty, x]) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} $ if and only if $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

I can't get my feet off the ground with this problem. Any help would be nice.